# How can I get name of through relation of has_many relation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, has-many

I have :

```
class Foo
   has_many :bar
   has_many :baz, through :bar
end


class FooTwo
   has_many :barTwo
   has_many :baz, through :barTwo
end
```

I need be abble to get through relation of baz association, like :

```
Foo.first.baz.relation_through #<=> Foo.first.bar
FooTwo.first.baz.relation_through #<=> Foo.first.barTwo
```

if it's impossible, can I get just the name? like :

```
Foo.first.baz.get_relation_through_name # "bar"
FooTwo.first.baz.get_relation_through_name # "barTwo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Foo.reflect_on_all_associations.find { |association| association.name == :baz}.options[:through]
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for this: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods/reflect_on_all_associations

```
Foo.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
```

and then pluck for the name.